# NetSuite - CSV import status search

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, csv-import

I want to get job status information of CSV imports in NetSuite by using SuiteScript. for this I used

```
search.create({
       type: search.Type.JOB_STATUS,
       filters: null,
       columns: ['internalid']
})
```

But I think I am using wrong search.

Answer (score 2):

You need  the  csv import ID,
If you are using suitecript

create your import

```
 var scriptTask = task.create({taskType: task.TaskType.CSV_IMPORT});
 scriptTask.mappingId = 201; //Id for you saved import for example
 var file = file.load({id: fileId});       
 scriptTask.importFile = file;
  var csvImportTaskId = scriptTask.submit(); //Here you get de CSV Import Id
```

After you get  the  csvimport id you can query the status:

```
   var csvTaskStatus = task.checkStatus({
                       taskId: csvImportTaskId 
                         });
   if (csvTaskStatus.status === task.TaskStatus.FAILED)   // you code goes here
```

This is the status that you will get

- PENDING
- PROCESSING
- COMPLETE
- FAILED

If you query the status right after you submit the csv Import you will always get pending status, you shoud wait some time csv import gets into a queue and it takes time to start processi

Comment: can I get status message like "1 of 1 records imported successfully" in script

Comment: I don´t think so, task.TaskStatus only return a ENUM  (pending,processing,complete,failed)

Comment: Thanks. In your solution the CSV import is happening by using SuiteScript task.create api. What if the Import is happening manually by user by going in Setup>Import/Export. can we track the status of task like this using SuiteScript? This scenario was my only question