# NetSuite CSV Response File

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, csv-import

I wanted status of CSV imports done in NetSuite. got the answer in [NetSuite - CSV import status search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63152421/netsuite-csv-import-status-search/63195806?noredirect=1#comment111812803_63195806). Thanks [user2615105](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615105/user2615105)

But if the user is doing the Import Manually, by going in Setup > Import/Export.

1. can we get the task status of the Import using SuiteScript in this scenario?
2. can we get the csv response file object or url since we can only access task.TaskStatus?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be able to use `N/task` and `N/search`.
2. The only file you can get after it's imported is the errors. They don't keep a record of the original file. But, if you load the file to the File Cabinet, you could get it using `N/file`. Just watch out for your account data limits.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I would guess no.